# EntityManagerFactory is closed - only on particular machine

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

My code constantly throws the "EntityManagerFactory is closed" exception.

The strange thing is - it only does so on our production machines. When I run the code with exact same configuration on my local machine, while connecting to exact same database - the errors don't appear. Another strange thing is - even though the exceptions keep getting thrown, it looks like Hibernate is somehow able to ignore them and successfully completes transactions. After a while though, it isn't able to complete any transactions and I am forced to restart application to make it work again (exceptions persist after a restart too).

I am injecting EntityManager into my DAO classes as follows:

```
 @PersistenceContext
 private EntityManager em;
```

I use these DAOs mostly from service methods annotated with @Transactional.

Stack trace:

```
2018-08-02 14:27:29,695 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6)) org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed
2018-08-02 14:27:29,695 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:450)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,695 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:378)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,695 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:474)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,695 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:289)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,695 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,695 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,695 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,695 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at xxx.services.examination.service.ExaminationDocumentService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ba40e12e.markDocumentError(<generated>)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,695 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at xxx.services.examination.listener.ExaminationListener.notification(ExaminationListener.java:68)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,696 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at com.impossibl.postgres.system.BasicContext.reportNotification(BasicContext.java:745)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,696 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at com.impossibl.postgres.protocol.v30.ProtocolImpl.receiveNotification(ProtocolImpl.java:1143)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,696 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at com.impossibl.postgres.protocol.v30.ProtocolImpl.dispatch(ProtocolImpl.java:781)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,696 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at com.impossibl.postgres.protocol.v30.MessageHandler.channelRead(MessageHandler.java:45)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,696 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,696 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,696 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,696 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,696 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,696 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,696 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,696 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,696 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,696 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,696 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,696 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,696 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:129)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,697 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:642)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,697 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:527)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,697 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:481)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,697 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:441)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,697 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,697 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,697 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6)) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed
2018-08-02 14:27:29,697 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.validateNotClosed(SessionFactoryImpl.java:531)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,697 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(SessionFactoryImpl.java:613)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,697 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(SessionFactoryImpl.java:154)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,697 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.createEntityManagerForTransaction(JpaTransactionManager.java:468)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,697 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:389)
2018-08-02 14:27:29,698 ERROR [stderr] (PG-JDBC EventLoop (6))  ... 31 more
(END)
```

My Spring configuration (config.xml) for hibernate-related beans looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">
    <jpa:repositories base-package="xxx.services.examination.dao"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- POSTGRES -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="listenerDataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <array>
                <value>xxx.services.examination</value>
            </array>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <!--<property name="showSql" value="true" />-->
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect"/>
            </bean>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    </bean>

    <bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
        <property name="poolName" value="springHikariCP" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="innerDataSource"/>
        <property name="connectionTimeout" value="60000"/>
        <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="${postgres.max.connection.pool}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean name="innerDataSource" class="com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDataSource">
        <property name="host" value="${postgres.host}"/>
        <property name="port" value="${postgres.port}"/>
        <property name="database" value="${postgres.database}"/>
        <property name="user" value="${postgres.user}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${postgres.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="listenerDataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig" />
    </bean>

    <!-- END POSTGRES -->


</beans>
```

My web.xml looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
        "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <display-name>xxx</display-name>

      <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:config.xml</param-value>
      </context-param>

      <listener>
        <listener-class>
          org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
      </listener>

</web-app>
```

Hibernate version: 5.3.1.Final
Spring version: 5.0.6.RELEASE
HikariCP version: 3.1.0

Comment: Then this is environment issue. Check if the database is reachable from that mashine as for starters.

Comment: @Antoniossss it is reachable, like I said - even though there are exceptions, hibernate still manages to somehow finish the transactions and entities are properly persisted into DB - at least up to some time. On top of that - there would be errors during applications startup, when the datasource is being instantiated if it wasn't reachable.

Comment: Looking at your scenario I guess your DB and Application are not running on Same Machine/Server. If so your DB connection is getting interrupted, Its hibernate which keep trying to reconnect and persist changes....

Comment: @AshishKumar it's exactly opposite. When it comes to the production environment - both application and db are on the same machine - that's where the problem occurs. It actually works fine when I run the application on my local machine while connecting to external DB

Comment: So when you deploy in Production. What IP you use for DB Configuration localhost or global IP ...

Comment: @AshishKumar global one

Comment: try in production config with localhost .....   instead of Global IP just to check

Comment: @AshishKumar  After changing it to localhost I get: Connection Error: Ident authentication failed for user. Most likely the psql server's port is only bind to external ip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, it turned out to be caused by configuration of the machine. The ulimits were too low and there were too many "heavy" process ran by single user, which led to quick saturation of the limits. Moving the limits up solved the problem.

Comment: Can you let me know what configurations are you talking about here. I am also facing a similar issue and suspect could be because of some configs.
And what limits are you talking about here?

Comment: I was talking about ulimit on linux server running the code: https://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html . The most relevant in this case would probably be the process and opened files limit.